# Laravel set null on empty array

Tags: laravel

i have something data like this [json data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p5HEr.png)

my problem is, how to set children to null if there is no data children.

[Menu Parent model](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J8AkG.png)

[Menu children Model](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fsT5n.png)

[Controller](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KOPz2.png)

Comment: Providing text instead of images helps to get much faster recommendations from the community

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
$data[] = [
    'id' => $men->id,
    'title' => $men->title,
    'icon' => $men->icon,
    'children' => (count($men->menuchild) > 0) ? $men->menuchild: null,
    ];
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest using the following code: ‌

```
$menus = Menuparent::all();

$data = [];

foreach ($menus as $menu){
    $data[] = [
        'id' => $menu->id,
        'title' => $menu->title,
        'icon' => $menu->icon,
        'children' => (count($menu->menuchild) > 0) ? $menu->menuchild: null,
    ];
}

return response()->json([
    'data' => $data
]);
```